# How to find missing implementations when inherit from e.g. openzeppelin

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I have the following code of a simple openzeppelin ERC721:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}
}
```

If I remove the constructor, I get a missing implementation error. My question is, where do I in ERC721.sol that I need to implement a constructor? Like in other languages when its e.g. marked as abstract.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

Comment: I know this code, but where is a keyword which is telling you in solidity that this method needs to be implemented?

Comment: ok I misunderstood your question. Constructor meant to be chained with the rules https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors . The parent ERC721 constructor has arguments which mean you have to pass arguments to it, no need for "abstract" or whatever keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about [constructor inheritance chaining here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors). In the parent contract (ERC721), the constructor requires arguments `(name_, symbol_)`. That's why you have to pass the arguments in your constructor. If the parent contract doesn't have contructor or has constructor without input argument, you don't have to specify your constructor.

In your code, if you don't want to write a constructor, you can do this with the same effect:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {
 // dont need constructor
}
```